# UICollectionView prepareForSegue indexPathForCell is nil iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

The problem is this line return nil:

```
if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForCell(sender as! UICollectionViewCell)
```

For that reason I can't pass any information, The identifier is set and the delegate is set.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "DetalleSegueIdentifier" {
        if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForCell(sender as! UICollectionViewCell) {
            let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetalleNoticiaViewController
            detailVC.contact = self.noticia[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("DetalleSegueIdentifier", sender: collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath))
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Where do you call your segue? On a button press? On the cell press?

Comment: Please, Show the portion of code where you call performSegueWithIdentifier

Comment: Put the portion of code where you call performSegueWithIdentifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the var collectionView is not reference in my ViewController for that reason always return nil. My mistake thanks you for your answers.

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how to try to get the cell back. You must pass the cell in the performSegueWithIdentifier and then recover it in prepareForSegue.
Here is the code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("DetalleSegueIdentifier", sender: collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath))
}
```

And then

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "DetalleSegueIdentifier" {
        if let cell = sender as? UICollectionViewCell{
            let indexPath = self.collectionView!.indexPathForCell(cell)
            let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetalleNoticiaViewController
            detailVC.contact = self.noticia[indexPath.row]

        }

    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this..

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("DetalleSegueIdentifier", sender: indexPath)
    }
```

and get your indexpath like this...

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "DetalleSegueIdentifier" {

            let aIndPath = sender as! NSIndexPath

            let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! DetalleNoticiaViewController
            detailVC.contact = self.noticia[aIndPath.item]
        }
    }
```